# Calc days based on Start and Finish date - MS project

Tags: ms-project

When I'm editing start or finish dates, Project moves the other based on the duration. How do I make it change the duration instead so I don't have to keep moving the start and finish dates back?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should never / rarely hard code a date in.  Open up the duration column and enter a new duration there.  Then let your schedule logic calculate the start and finish dates based on your schedule network.

Comment: But what if I need to have the task finish at a hard date? The task doesn't take the whole duration, it just needs to be done by the end date and start after the beginning date.

Comment: Set your duration so that task will end at your desired date.  Set a baseline and the baseline finish date will not move.  However, you want the calculated date to move both left and right based on performance.  That way, you can calculate the finish variance to determine if you have a growing problem.